# getting testloading results in artillery

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, load-testing

I need to get loadtesting results: I send the server (post) info about me (user id and game name) and the server assigns me a player handle and a session id. I want to get these back but the issue is that I can only find them in the url (they appear like so: url.com/#playerhandle=number&sessionid=number) and cannot seem to retrieve them using artillery.

```
{
"config": {
    "target": "sever/game",
    "phases": [
        {"duration": 10, "arrivalRate": 200}
    ]
},
"scenarios": [
    {
        "name": "test1",
        "flow": [
            {"post": {
                "url": "/initialize",
                "json": {"userId": "{{ Date.now() }}", "gameName": "game_Blood"}
            }
        },
            {"get": {
                "url": "/initialize",
                "body": "playerHandle={{ ph }}&sessionId={{ sid }}"
            }}
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This is what I got so far. Obviously this doesnt work. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with the script that jump out immediately:

1. `Date.now()` is being used in a template - that won't work as arbitrary JS expressions are not supported. The value for `userId` could be read in from an external CSV file instead, see the docs on [reading variables from a file](https://artillery.io/docs/testing_http.html#variables-from-a-file).
2. If the session id and the player handle are only available in the URL (does the server redirect to that URL after the POST request?), those can be extracted with an [`afterResponse` hook](https://artillery.io/docs/testing_http.html#advanced-writing-custom-logic-in-javascript) - `response.headers.location` will contain that URL. Once the required values are extracted, they can be made available to subsequent requests by inserting new values into `context.vars`.